# How do I calculate random integers than add those random integers together?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am a beginner at swift just starting, I am trying to code in swift a code that generates a random number and display it on two labels onto my screen. After I'd like to calculate the sum of those two randomly generated numbers. It gives an error message when I calculate the sum though.

```
@IBOutlet weak var number1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var number2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var number3: UILabel!

let randomInt1 = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
let randomInt2 = Int.random(in: 1..<10)

@IBAction func StartButton(_ sender: Any) {
    number1.text = String(randomInt1)
    number2.text = String(randomInt2)
    var answer1 = [Int]()
    answer1[1] = randomInt1 + randomInt2
```

note: I tried to use this code but it gives an error message when I try and play it

Comment: The code above is on UIKit, isn't it?

Comment: Issue is in this line of code.
var answer1 = [Int]()
 answer1[1] = randomInt1 + randomInt2 // There is no index in answer1 you need to append the value in it.
answer1.append(randomInt1 + randomInt2) // this will fix the issue.

Comment: Swift is the programming language, SwiftUI is a UI framework.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this.I have refactor some code like moved you answer1 array to top so you can access your answers. The way you were doing. It would be out of memory because of it's scope.

```
     @IBOutlet weak var number1: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var number2: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var number3: UILabel!
        
      let randomInt1 = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
      let randomInt2 = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
      var answer1 = [Int]()
        
      @IBAction func StartButton(_ sender: Any) {
            number1.text = String(randomInt1)
            number2.text = String(randomInt2)
            
            answer1.append(randomInt1 + randomInt2)
       }
```